# Pip not working inside Virtual Env but works outside perfectly

Tags: python, pip, open-source, virtualenv, portal

Hello Guys I am tying to follow the installation here https://github.com/systers/portal and trying to deploy the server inside a virtual environment on my machine.
After lots of errors I decided to install a fresh copy of Ubuntu 16.04 and start
After the installation here are the things that I have installed using the given commands

I checked my current python and python3 versions using python --version and python3--version respectively and they are Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2 respectively.

```
Easy Install. $ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential  
pip. $ sudo easy_install pip
virtualenv. $ sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv.
python3-dev tools.$sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Now after that I created a virtual env and activated it using the following commands

```
$ virtualenv venv1 --python=/usr/bin/python3
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

But now when I run the third command

```
$ pip install -r requirements/dev.txt
```

or even do

```
$pip --version
```

I get the error

```
bash: /media/rohan/New Volume/portal/venv1/bin/pip: "/media/rohan/New: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Also in /venv1/bin the files pip,pip3 ,pip3.5 are present

I tried sudo easy_install pip thinking that it will install pip in the virtual environment but it installs to /usr/local/bin

Also I tried by creating a virtual env using the code

```
$virtualenv venv --python=/usr/bin/python
```

But that also doesnt work and this time also same error comes and in /venv/bin pip pip2 pip2.7 are present

PLEASE HELP

Comment: Please complete te post, also include the errors

Comment: sorry it got posted by accident i didnt realize it
Now its completed please check

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem appears to be that the path to your virtualenv has a space in it that isn't being escaped somewhere it should be.

Note the error you receive:

```
/media/rohan/New: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

So with that space in the path, it is trying to run a program that doesn't exist (`/media/rohan/New`) on a file that doesn't exist (`Volume/portal/venv1/bin/pip`).

Renaming `New Volume` to something without spaces like `new_volume` and then recreating a virtualenv should resolve this.

Comment: Nice catch. I really think this should be fixed in virtualenv.  Unix devs/admins have been handling the issue of spaces in filenames/paths for decades yet there is a [dispute about how to handle it in virtualenv](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/53).

Comment: Okay, this should be fixed in the future. That was really annoying me lol

Answer (score 0):

I had renamed the folder of virtual environment so that I was getting this error.
Then I renamed the venv folder name to the path mentioned in the error (That is the one which I had named while creating venv.) then tried to use pip and it worked.

Might be you have already solved your issue, but this is for the future visitors.